# No configuration setting found for key typesafe config

Tags: scala, typesafe-config

Im trying to implement  a configuration  tool [typesafehub/config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config) 
im using this code

```
 val conf = ConfigFactory.load()
 val url = conf.getString("add.prefix") + id + "/?" + conf.getString("add.token")
```

And the location  of the property file is  **/src/main/resources/application.conf**

But for some reason i'm receiving

```
com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'add'
```

File content

```
add {
  token = "access_token=6235uhC9kG05ulDtG8DJDA"
  prefix = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/"
  limit = "&limit=250"
  comments="?pretty=0&limit=250&access_token=69kG05ulDtG8DJDA&filter=stream"
  feed="/feed?limit=200&access_token=623501EuhC9kG05ulDtG8DJDA&pretty=0"
}
```

Everything looks configured correctly ??  do i missed something .

thanks,

miki

Comment: What's the content of application.conf?

Comment: @Paul i added the file content

Comment: @MIkCode how you resolved this issue ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The error message is telling you that whatever configuration got read, it didn't include a top level setting named `add`.  The `ConfigFactory.load` function will attempt to load the configuration from a variety of places. By default it will look for a file named `application` with a suffix of `.conf` or `.json`. It looks for that file as a Java resource on your class path. However, various system properties will override this default behavior.

So, it is likely that what you missed is one of these:

- Is it possible that `src/main/resources` is not on your class path?
- Are the `config.file`, `config.resource` or `config.url` properties set?
- Is your `application.conf` file empty?
- Do you have an `application.conf` that would be found earlier in your class path?
- Is the key: `add` defined in the `application.conf`?

Comment: For completeness I would add that this error might also happen when after you var assignment you add java-like comments. That is, using // instead of #.

Comment: In my case the key was omitted in the application.conf file

Comment: in resources folder i kept application.properties file , how to load it into the program and I want to distinguish between prod and dev properties...plz help me

Comment: Rename it application.conf. Typesafe Config does not read .properties files only .conf files as it's files are not in Java properties syntax.

Answer (score 5):

Are you using an IDE or sbt? 
I had a similar problem while using Eclipse. It simply did not find the application.conf file at first and later on failed to notice edits. 
However, once I ran my program via sbt, all worked just fine, including Eclipse. So, I added 'main/resources' to the libraries (Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries", "add class folder"). That might help you as well.

Answer (score 4):

Place your application.conf in the src folder and it should work

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this issue inside a Specs2 test that was driven by SBT.  It turned out that the issue was caused by https://github.com/etorreborre/specs2/issues/556.  In that case, the Thread's contextClassLoader wasn't using the correct classloader.  If you run into a similar error, there are other versions of ConfigFactory.load() that allow you to pass the current class's ClassLoader instead.  If you're using Specs2 and you're seeing this issue, use a version <= 3.8.6 or >= 4.0.1.

Comment: Same thing happened to me with ScalaTest.  All of the sudden, I started getting this error.  Your solution worked!  `ConfigFractory.load(this.getClass().getClassLoader())`

Answer (score 3):

Check you path. In my case I got the same issue, having application.conf placed in src/main/resources/configuration/common/application.conf

**Incorrect:**

```
val conf = ConfigFactory.load(s"/configuration/common/application.conf")
```

**Correct**

```
val conf = ConfigFactory.load(s"configuration/common/application.conf")
```

it turned out to be a silly mistake i made.

Following that, i does not matter if you use ":" or "=" in .conf file.

Getting the value from example:

```
server{
       proc {
             max = "600"
            }
      }
conf.getString("server.proc.max")
```

Even you can have the following conf:

```
 proc {
                 max = "600"
                }
 proc {
                main = "60000"
                }
conf.getString("proc.max") //prints 600

conf.getString("proc.min") //prints 60000
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this doing a `getString` on an integer in my configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into exactly the same problem and the solution was to replace `=` with `:` in the `application.conf`. Try with the following content in your `application.conf`:

```
add {
  token: "access_token=6235uhC9kG05ulDtG8DJDA"
  prefix: "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/"
  limit: "&limit=250"
  comments: "?pretty=0&limit=250&access_token=69kG05ulDtG8DJDA&filter=stream"
  feed: "/feed?limit=200&access_token=623501EuhC9kG05ulDtG8DJDA&pretty=0"
}
```

Strangely, IntelliJ doesn't detect any formatting or syntax error when using `=` for me.

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was a stupid mistake, 
i m change file name from "application.config" to "application.conf" and its works .

Answer (score 0):

If the `application.conf` is not getting discovered, you could add this to `build.sbt`:

```
unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile += baseDirectory.value / "main/resources"
```

Please don't use this to include any custom path. Follow the guidelines and [best-practices](https://github.com/lightbend/config#how-to-handle-defaults)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, make sure the application.conf is place in: src/main/resources.

I placed the file there error went away.

Looking at these examples helped me as well:
https://github.com/lightbend/config/tree/main/examples/scala

Answer (score 0):

Use ConfigFactory.parseFile for other locations